# Exception when making select on datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

This is my code

```
var compainNames = (from row in DTgraph.AsEnumerable()
                                group row by row.Field<string>("Campaign") into grp
                                select new
                                {
                                    CampaignName = grp.Key
                                }).ToList();

 var dataForOneCampaint = DTgraph.Select("Campaign = " + compainNames[i].ToString()).ToList();
```

where `DTgraph` is a datatable.

I got this exception:

> Cannot interpret token '{' at position 12.

Could you help please?

I debug and i can see that `compainNames` has 3 strings

the exception in this line

```
 var dataForOneCampaint = DTgraph.Select("Campaign = " + compainNames[i].ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the value of `compainNames[i]` exactly? Debug and tell us.

Comment: start by printing out compainNames in the debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method use the same rules with [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for creating filters.

From it's documentation;

> User-Defined Values
>
> User-defined values may be used within expressions to be compared with
>   column values. **String values should be enclosed within single
>   quotation marks** (and each single quotation character in a string value
>   has to be escaped by prepending it with another single quotation
>   character).

I believe you can use;

```
var dataForOneCampaint = DTgraph
                        .Select("Campaign = '" + compainNames[i].ToString() + "'")
                        .ToList();
```

Or use `String.Format` as Felipe [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23176405/447156).

Comment: folloing your solution, the dataForOneCampaint is empty, althought the DTgraph has campaing exactly existed in compainNames

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `'` char between the `string`, for sample:

```
var dataForOneCampaint = DTgraph
                        .Select(string.Format("Campaign = '{0}'", compainNames[i].ToString()))
                        .ToList();
```